# Angular JS with ng-pattern-restrict email Validation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I am using ng-pattern-restrict to prevent people from entering invalid emails 
according to valid email addresses at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address
Here is what I have so far:

```
^([\w!#$%&'*/~|`}{^+-]+(.|@)?)*$
```

This will prevent .@ from occurring next to one another. It also prevents from @. from appearing at the beginning. Notice I do not care if the expression is blank as required tag in my input field will not allow submission unless the form is filled out. What I can not figure out is after @ is in the expression it should be prevented from used again. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just look for any combination of numbers and letters, a literal '@', any combination of letters, a literal '.', and then any combination of letters?

Comment: _"What regex to use to validate email address"_ has been asked on SO seven-thousand-three-hundred-and-nineteen times. The answer is ***"don't"***. Especially now with HTML5, you can use `<input type="email">`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: _"It also prevents from @. from appearing at the beginning."_ **and** _"after @ is in the expression it should be prevented from used again."_ — Both of these rules would exclude legal (valid) email addresses. Email is `address@domain` and the `address` part can be _absolutely anything in the world_ if it is properly escaped, because it is _up to the `domain` part_ to make sense of it.